# Is a collection of useful functions best kept as a function library or should it be converted to a class?

Tags: php, class, function

I am in the process of modernising some of my sites. The old database access routines are now safely wrapped in classes along with the page rendering routines etc.

But I am left with a selection of useful, generic functions, all happily residing in a single php file.

I've read that I should convert these to an anonymous class, and reference them like this:

```
$output1 = myfuncs::function1(...);
$output2 = myfuncs::function2(...);
```

Now, I understand that it makes sense to do this to prevent duplicate function names if I should use somebody else's code, but is there any other reason why I should do it this way, instead of sticking with a function library? A function library would be quicker, for a start. I know this is fairly irrelevent in this day and age, but I think the following code also looks less clunky:

```
$output1 = function1(...);
$output2 = function2(...);
```

I am not against oop per se, I love my new classes for data access and rendering, but is it really necessary to make everything oop?

Comment: I really do wish that the people who put things on hold in this place and could just leave questions alone. If a question is spam then people will downvote it to oblivion. Do we really need this kind of policing? I had a valid question and I have been happy with the responses I have got so far, thank you very much.

Comment: putting all your utility functions in a class with a namespace could allow you to write tests for them as unit test frameworks work on object oriented code. That's the only real benefit I could find in my own project.

Comment: "Do we really need this kind of policing" - yes, definitely. The proportion of opinion-based/unanswerable/unresearched items in the PHP tag is huge (not saying yours is that bad, but it is still subjective).

Comment: FWIW, I'd use classes that are instantiated, rather than accessed statically. It means you have less hardwiring in your application, and you easily swap out a class for a subclass (or a totally different one) if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read that I should convert these (generic functions) to an anonymous class ...

Don't do that. This is considered (the worst kind of) class oriented programming, because other than being a wrapper around your functions, they serve no other purpose.

Instead, use [namespaces](http://php.net/namespace) to organize your functional code:

```
namespace Utils;

function foo() { }

function bar() { }
```

Then, to use it:

```
require 'Utils.php';

use Utils\bar;

Utils\foo();
bar();
```

> but is it really necessary to make everything oop?

Nope. PHP allows you to mix and match, so do whatever you feel comfortable doing.

Comment: +1 for the clearest demonstration of namespace usage I've seen!

Answer (score 2):

My answer: **depends**. Sometimes it is better to declare just functions, sometimes classes.

My point is that your code must be **readable** and **reusable**.

A great example in Java:

`class Math` contains  plenty of useful functions that are related somehow to math. What do we know about the class? Its static methods  will most probably accept `numeric parameters` and return `numeric values` / `boolean values`.

```
Math.abs()
Math.cos()
Math.sin()
Math.sqrt()
```

And so on. Just a perfect set of tools. Class may be a great toolbox.

Also, coding may be really comfortable, because some IDEs may quickly list you all the static functions the class contains as you start writing `Math.`

When declaring a class instead of just simple functions, you could track / log their usage inside the class and share some instance variable.

Comment: +1 its a good point about the IDEs. I hadn't considered that one.

Comment: Java has no functions, so comparing to Java has to be taken with caution. The IDE's completion also works when using a prefix like `math_` or namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a philosophical difference in the answer to this question, the computer is indifferent to the manner in which you gave it instructions.

An object incapsulates state information which it implicitly references when being called, this is essentially the same as calling a function and giving it a structure to manipulate.

The only time it would be useful to convert your functional paradigm code to object oriented code is if you can conceive of a time when you might create a subclass that provides very similar behaviour, but which alters certain behaviours.

Other than that, classes do indeed help with namespaces, but as mentioned above,php provides namespaces for functional paradigm php.